# Better solution for mongoid many to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

The mongoid documentation told me that n-n relations `should be used with caution`
I understand his but don't have an idea how to solve my problem a better way using pure mongoid:

A course has many participants and a participant could participate with many courses. So wouldn't it be faster to store the participant on the course model and do a search over all courses when all courses of a participant are needed?

Answer (score 1):

Your model should be reflective of your use cases.

One way to do this would be to have one model for the courses, one for participants and a 3rd that maps students to courses (with a unique index on course & student to prevent duplicates). This way there is a single model referring to the other 2. This may or may not be ideal based on your access patterns.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is probably a good use case for embedding documents. See the sample syntax on the front page for embeds_many and embedded_in: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/

The main downside here is that if you have participants in more than one course, you will have duplicate participants in each of those courses.

Make sure you put an index on the fields you plan to do your lookups for participants with.